# Setting SelectedItem in ListView when user clicks in ItemTemplate Textbox

Tags: wpf, listview, textbox, selecteditem, itemtemplate

I have the following ListView (simplified):

```
<ListView Name="lvwNotes" KeyUp="lvwNotes_KeyUp">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <DockPanel Background="LightGray">
                     <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Author}" />
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Timestamp}" />
                </DockPanel>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                         GotFocus = "lvwNotes_TextBox_GotFocus"
                         TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Changing the selected item through a click only works when the user clicks on the DockPanel with the TextBlocks, but not on clicking the TextBox. What I want to achieve is to set the selected item to that one containing the TextBox into which the user clicked.

I managed to get through to the ListViewItem related to the TextBox:

```
private void lvwNotes_TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    DependencyObject o = Tools.GetAncestorByType((DependencyObject)sender, typeof(ListViewItem));
    if (!o.Equals(null)) {
        // code to select this ListViewItem
    }
}
```

But setting

```
lvwNotes.SelectedIten = o ;
```

remains without effect. I've tried also some tricks with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, but to be honest, I don't exactly know what I'm doing there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your code

```
<ListView.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.Resources>
```

Comment: You may even remove the event handler for GotFocus.

Answer (score 2):

The `DataContext` unless explicitly changed in the `DataTemplate` is the current item, hence:

```
private void lvwNotes_TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = (TextBox)sender;
    lvwNotes.SelectedItem = tb.DataContext;
}
```